# How can I override an action controller that inherited from a base controller asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hello guys I was wondering if there a way to override an action controller that inherited from a base controller just for add a filter attribute , this filter attribute allows to validate if a user has a certain permission to execute an action controller , here’s my base controller.

```
public class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : Entity<int>

{

    private readonly IEntityService<T> _service;


    public BaseController(IEntityService<T> service )
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public BaseController()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllEntities()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }



}
```

And here's my sub controller that I want to add the filter attribute note the code below is incorrect but I want to do something like this ,  do you know how to do it ? thanks for your attention..

```
public class ArbitrosController : BaseController<Arbitro>
{


    public ArbitrosController(IArbitroService _ArbitroService):base( _ArbitroService )
    {

    }

    [HasPermission("get")]//filter atribute
    public new IEnumerable<Arbitro> GetAllEntities()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `virtual` keyword in base class and `override` in descendant. To access base class from overrided you can use `base` keyword:

```
public class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : Entity<int>
{
    ...
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAllEntities()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }
}

public class ArbitrosController : BaseController<Arbitro>
{
    ...
    [HasPermission("get")]//filter atribute
    public override IEnumerable<Arbitro> GetAllEntities()
    {
       return base.GetAllEntities();
    }
}
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) about inheritance in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much @andrew that's exactly what I needed